# OpenGL error combining renderer text from ttf and background texture

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, freetype

I am having a problem with Opengl and Opengl ES. I want to make squares with png image textures and render text in front of these squares.

I can make squares with textures from png images, and I can render text from ttf like in [this example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Text_Rendering_02), but it works only if not executing at the same time. I will try to explain better (The example code is too dirty because the code I'm getting from one software is more structured and bigger, and this code is only for an example):

I have one GLProgram with one Vertex Shader and one Fragment Shader for texture squares. I have another GLProgram with another Vertex Shader and another Fragment Shader to make Renderer text.

If I load all the GL programs and only draw each frame only the texture square, I can see it perfectly.

If I draw the renderer text (using his GLprogram) before or after the texture square (doing his glUseProgram before drawing the square) I can only see the texture text on screen and the background color that's created with (glClearColor(x.xf, x.xf, x.xf, x.xf)) and I can't see the texture square.

Does anyone know where the error is in the code?

Now I will post the shaders and the example source code:

back.v.glsl:

```
attribute vec4 g_vPosition;
attribute vec3 g_vColor;
attribute vec2 g_vTexCoord;

varying   vec3 g_vVSColor;
varying   vec2 g_vVSTexCoord;

void main()                 
{                               
    gl_Position  = g_vPosition; 
    g_vVSColor = g_vColor;              
    g_vVSTexCoord = g_vTexCoord;            
}
```

back.f.glsl:

```
uniform sampler2D s_texture;
varying   vec3      g_vVSColor; 
varying   vec2 g_vVSTexCoord;

void main()                     
{                               
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(s_texture,g_vVSTexCoord);  
}
```

text.v.glsl:

```
attribute vec4 coord;
varying vec2 texpos;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = vec4(coord.xy, 0, 1);
  texpos = coord.zw;
}
```

text.f.glsl:

```
varying vec2 texpos;
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform vec4 color;

void main(void) {
  //gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, texture2D(tex, texpos).a) * color;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb, texture2D(tex, texpos).a);
}
```

Source Code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <EGL/egl.h>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <png.h>

EGLDisplay          egldisplay;
EGLConfig           eglconfig;
EGLSurface          eglsurface;
EGLContext          eglcontext;
EGLNativeWindowType eglNativeWindow;
EGLNativeDisplayType eglNativeDisplayType;

#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

GLuint program;
GLint attribute_coord;
GLint uniform_tex;
GLint uniform_color;

GLuint programBack;
GLint coordBack = 0;
GLint texBack = 2;
GLint colorBack = 1;

struct point {
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat s;
    GLfloat t;
};

GLuint vbo;

FT_Library ft;
FT_Face face;

// Maximum texture width
#define MAXWIDTH 800

const char *fontfilename;

float VertexColors[] = {

    /* Red */
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    /* Red */
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

    /* Green */
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

    /* Green */
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

};

float VertexTexCoords[] = {
    /* Front Face */
    0.0f,0.0f,
    1.0f,0.0f,
    0.0f,1.0f,
    1.0f,1.0f,
};

float fBackgroundPosition[12] = {
    /* Bottom Left Of The Quad (Front) */
    -1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,
    /* Bottom Right Of The Quad (Front) */
    1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,
    /* Top Left Of The Quad (Front) */
    -1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,
    /* Top Right Of The Quad (Front) */
    1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,
};

GLuint glTextures[4];


/**
 * The atlas struct holds a texture that contains the visible US-ASCII characters
 * of a certain font rendered with a certain character height.
 * It also contains an array that contains all the information necessary to
 * generate the appropriate vertex and texture coordinates for each character.
 *
 * After the constructor is run, you don't need to use any FreeType functions anymore.
 */
struct atlas {
    GLuint tex;     // texture object

    unsigned int w;         // width of texture in pixels
    unsigned int h;         // height of texture in pixels

    struct {
        float ax;   // advance.x
        float ay;   // advance.y

        float bw;   // bitmap.width;
        float bh;   // bitmap.height;

        float bl;   // bitmap_left;
        float bt;   // bitmap_top;

        float tx;   // x offset of glyph in texture coordinates
        float ty;   // y offset of glyph in texture coordinates
    } c[256];       // character information

    atlas(FT_Face face, int height) {
        FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, height);
        FT_GlyphSlot g = face->glyph;

        unsigned int roww = 0;
        unsigned int rowh = 0;
        w = 0;
        h = 0;

        memset(c, 0, sizeof c);

        /* Find minimum size for a texture holding all visible ASCII characters */
        //for (int i = 32; i < 128; i++) {
        for (int i = 32; i < 254; i++) {
            if (FT_Load_Char(face, i, FT_LOAD_RENDER)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Loading character %c failed!\n", i);
                continue;
            }
            if (roww + g->bitmap.width + 1 >= MAXWIDTH) {
                w = std::max(w, roww);
                h += rowh;
                roww = 0;
                rowh = 0;
            }
            roww += g->bitmap.width + 1;
            rowh = std::max(rowh, g->bitmap.rows);
        }

        w = std::max(w, roww);
        h += rowh;

        /* Create a texture that will be used to hold all ASCII glyphs */
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glGenTextures(1, &tex);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
        glUniform1i(uniform_tex, 0);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, w, h, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

        /* We require 1 byte alignment when uploading texture data */
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

        /* Clamping to edges is important to prevent artifacts when scaling */
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        /* Linear filtering usually looks best for text */
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        /* Paste all glyph bitmaps into the texture, remembering the offset */
        int ox = 0;
        int oy = 0;

        rowh = 0;

        //for (int i = 32; i < 128; i++) {
        for (int i = 32; i < 254; i++) {
            if (FT_Load_Char(face, i, FT_LOAD_RENDER)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Loading character %c failed!\n", i);
                continue;
            }

            if (ox + g->bitmap.width + 1 >= MAXWIDTH) {
                oy += rowh;
                rowh = 0;
                ox = 0;
            }

            glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, ox, oy, g->bitmap.width, g->bitmap.rows, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, g->bitmap.buffer);
            c[i].ax = g->advance.x >> 6;
            c[i].ay = g->advance.y >> 6;

            c[i].bw = g->bitmap.width;
            c[i].bh = g->bitmap.rows;

            c[i].bl = g->bitmap_left;
            c[i].bt = g->bitmap_top;

            c[i].tx = ox / (float)w;
            c[i].ty = oy / (float)h;

            rowh = std::max(rowh, g->bitmap.rows);
            ox += g->bitmap.width + 1;
        }

        fprintf(stderr, "Generated a %d x %d (%d kb) texture atlas\n", w, h, w * h / 1024);
    }

    ~atlas() {
        glDeleteTextures(1, &tex);
    }
};

atlas *a48;
atlas *a24;
atlas *a12;


//#define GL_ES_VERSION_2_0

/**
 * Store all the file's contents in memory, useful to pass shaders
 * source code to OpenGL
 */
char* file_read(const char* filename)
{
    FILE* in = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (in == NULL) return NULL;

    int res_size = BUFSIZ;
    char* res = (char*)malloc(res_size);
    int nb_read_total = 0;

    while (!feof(in) && !ferror(in)) {
        if (nb_read_total + BUFSIZ > res_size) {
            if (res_size > 10 * 1024 * 1024) break;
            res_size = res_size * 2;
            res = (char*)realloc(res, res_size);
        }
        char* p_res = res + nb_read_total;
        nb_read_total += fread(p_res, 1, BUFSIZ, in);
    }

    fclose(in);
    res = (char*)realloc(res, nb_read_total + 1);
    res[nb_read_total] = '\0';
    return res;
}

/**
 * Compile the shader from file 'filename', with error handling
 */
GLuint create_shader(const char* filename, GLenum type)
{
    const GLchar* source = file_read(filename);
    if (source == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening %s: ", filename); perror("");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        printf("Load shader correctly %s\n", filename);
    }
    GLuint res = glCreateShader(type);
    const GLchar* sources[] = {
        // Define GLSL version
#ifdef GL_ES_VERSION_2_0
        "#version 100\n"  // OpenGL ES 2.0
#else
        "#version 120\n"  // OpenGL 2.1
#endif
        ,
        // GLES2 precision specifiers
#ifdef GL_ES_VERSION_2_0
        // Define default float precision for fragment shaders:
        (type == GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER) ?
        "#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH\n"
        "precision highp float;           \n"
        "#else                            \n"
        "precision mediump float;         \n"
        "#endif                           \n"
        : ""
        // Note: OpenGL ES automatically defines this:
        // #define GL_ES
#else
        // Ignore GLES 2 precision specifiers:
        "#define lowp   \n"
        "#define mediump\n"
        "#define highp  \n"
#endif
        ,
        source };
    glShaderSource(res, 3, sources, NULL);
    free((void*)source);

    glCompileShader(res);
    GLint compile_ok = GL_FALSE;
    glGetShaderiv(res, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_ok);
    if (compile_ok == GL_FALSE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:", filename);
        //print_log(res);
        glDeleteShader(res);
        return 0;
    }

    return res;
}

GLuint create_program(const char *vertexfile, const char *fragmentfile) {
    printf("Creating program\n");

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    GLuint shader;

    printf("Loading program\n");

    if (vertexfile) {
        shader = create_shader(vertexfile, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        if (!shader)
            return 0;
        glAttachShader(program, shader);
    }

    if (fragmentfile) {
        shader = create_shader(fragmentfile, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        if (!shader)
            return 0;
        glAttachShader(program, shader);
    }

    glLinkProgram(program);
    GLint link_ok = GL_FALSE;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &link_ok);
    if (!link_ok) {
        fprintf(stderr, "glLinkProgram:");
        //print_log(program);
        glDeleteProgram(program);
        return 0;
    }

    return program;
}

GLint get_attrib(GLuint program, const char *name) {
    GLint attribute = glGetAttribLocation(program, name);
    if (attribute == -1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind attribute %s\n", name);
    return attribute;
}

GLint get_uniform(GLuint program, const char *name) {
    GLint uniform = glGetUniformLocation(program, name);
    if (uniform == -1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind uniform %s\n", name);
    return uniform;
}

bool bLoadPngImage(char *name, int &outWidth, int &outHeight, bool &outHasAlpha, GLubyte **outData) {
    png_structp png_ptr;
    png_infop info_ptr;
    unsigned int sig_read = 0;
    int color_type, interlace_type;
    FILE *fp;

    if ((fp = fopen(name, "rb")) == NULL)
        return false;

    /* Create and initialize the png_struct
     * with the desired error handler
     * functions.  If you want to use the
     * default stderr and longjump method,
     * you can supply NULL for the last
     * three parameters.  We also supply the
     * the compiler header file version, so
     * that we know if the application
     * was compiled with a compatible version
     * of the library.  REQUIRED
     */
    png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING,
        NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (png_ptr == NULL) {
        fclose(fp);
        return false;
    }

    /* Allocate/initialize the memory
    * for image information.  REQUIRED. */
    info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
    if (info_ptr == NULL) {
        fclose(fp);
        png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, NULL, NULL);
        return false;
    }

    /* Set error handling if you are
     * using the setjmp/longjmp method
     * (this is the normal method of
     * doing things with libpng).
     * REQUIRED unless you  set up
     * your own error handlers in
     * the png_create_read_struct()
     * earlier.
     */
    if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr))) {
        /* Free all of the memory associated
         * with the png_ptr and info_ptr */
        png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, NULL);
        fclose(fp);
        /* If we get here, we had a
         * problem reading the file */
        return false;
    }

    /* Set up the output control if
     * you are using standard C streams */
    png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);

    /* If we have already
     * read some of the signature */
    png_set_sig_bytes(png_ptr, sig_read);

    /*
     * If you have enough memory to read
     * in the entire image at once, and
     * you need to specify only
     * transforms that can be controlled
     * with one of the PNG_TRANSFORM_*
     * bits (this presently excludes
     * dithering, filling, setting
     * background, and doing gamma
     * adjustment), then you can read the
     * entire image (including pixels)
     * into the info structure with this
     * call
     *
     * PNG_TRANSFORM_STRIP_16 |
     * PNG_TRANSFORM_PACKING  forces 8 bit
     * PNG_TRANSFORM_EXPAND forces to
     *  expand a palette into RGB
     */
    png_read_png(png_ptr, info_ptr, PNG_TRANSFORM_STRIP_16 | PNG_TRANSFORM_PACKING | PNG_TRANSFORM_EXPAND, NULL);

    png_uint_32 width, height;
    int bit_depth;
    png_get_IHDR(png_ptr, info_ptr, &width, &height, &bit_depth, &color_type,
        &interlace_type, NULL, NULL);
    outWidth = width;
    outHeight = height;

    unsigned int row_bytes = png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    *outData = (unsigned char*)malloc(row_bytes * outHeight);

    png_bytepp row_pointers = png_get_rows(png_ptr, info_ptr);

    for (int i = 0; i < outHeight; i++) {
        // note that png is ordered top to
        // bottom, but OpenGL expect it bottom to top
        // so the order or swapped
        memcpy(*outData + (row_bytes * (outHeight - 1 - i)), row_pointers[i], row_bytes);
    }

    /* Clean up after the read,
     * and free any memory allocated */
    png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, NULL);

    /* Close the file */
    fclose(fp);

    /* That's it */
    return true;
}

void vLoadPngToTexture(std::string sFilename, int iTexture) {
    GLubyte *glTextureImage;
    int iWidth, iHeight;
    bool bHasAlpha;
    //char filename[] = "/home/root/res/drawable/disclaimerantamina.png";
    //bool success = bLoadPngImage((char *)sFilename.c_str(), iWidth, iHeight, bHasAlpha, &glTextureImage);
    //if (!success) {
    if (!bLoadPngImage((char *)sFilename.c_str(), iWidth, iHeight, bHasAlpha, &glTextureImage)) {
        std::cout << "Unable to load png file" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    std::cout << "Image loaded " << sFilename << " " << iWidth << " " << iHeight << " alpha " << bHasAlpha << std::endl;

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextures[iTexture]);
    /* Generate The Texture */
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, iWidth,
        iHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        glTextureImage);
    /* Linear Filtering */
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    std::cout << "Texture loaded " << iTexture << " - " << sFilename << std::endl;
}

int init_resources() {
    /* Initialize the FreeType2 library */
    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not init freetype library\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* Load a font */
    if (FT_New_Face(ft, fontfilename, 0, &face)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open font %s\n", fontfilename);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Load Font Correctly\n");

    program = create_program("text.v.glsl", "text.f.glsl");
    if (program == 0)
        return 0;

    printf("Create program Correctly\n");

    attribute_coord = get_attrib(program, "coord");
    uniform_tex = get_uniform(program, "tex");
    uniform_color = get_uniform(program, "color");

    if (attribute_coord == -1 || uniform_tex == -1 || uniform_color == -1)
        return 0;

    printf("Create attributes Correctly\n");

    programBack = create_program("back.v.glsl", "back.f.glsl");

    printf("Create program Background Correctly\n");

    coordBack = get_attrib(programBack, "g_vPosition");
    //colorBack = get_attrib(programBack, "g_vColor");
    texBack = get_attrib(programBack, "g_vTexCoord");

    if (coordBack == -1 || colorBack == -1 || texBack == -1)
        return 0;

    // Create the vertex buffer object
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    ///* Create texture atlasses for several font sizes */
    a48 = new atlas(face, 48);
    a24 = new atlas(face, 24);
    a12 = new atlas(face, 12);

    return 1;
}

/**
 * Render text using the currently loaded font and currently set font size.
 * Rendering starts at coordinates (x, y), z is always 0.
 * The pixel coordinates that the FreeType2 library uses are scaled by (sx, sy).
 */
void render_text(const char *text, atlas * a, float x, float y, float sx, float sy) {
    const uint8_t *p;

    /* Use the texture containing the atlas */
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, a->tex);
    glUniform1i(uniform_tex, 0);

    /* Set up the VBO for our vertex data */
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_coord);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(attribute_coord, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    point coords[6 * strlen(text)];
    int c = 0;

    /* Loop through all characters */
    for (p = (const uint8_t *)text; *p; p++) {
        /* Calculate the vertex and texture coordinates */
        float x2 = x + a->c[*p].bl * sx;
        float y2 = -y - a->c[*p].bt * sy;
        float w = a->c[*p].bw * sx;
        float h = a->c[*p].bh * sy;

        /* Advance the cursor to the start of the next character */
        x += a->c[*p].ax * sx;
        y += a->c[*p].ay * sy;

        /* Skip glyphs that have no pixels */
        if (!w || !h)
            continue;

        coords[c++] = (point) {
            x2, -y2, a->c[*p].tx, a->c[*p].ty
        };
        coords[c++] = (point) {
            x2 + w, -y2, a->c[*p].tx + a->c[*p].bw / a->w, a->c[*p].ty
        };
        coords[c++] = (point) {
            x2, -y2 - h, a->c[*p].tx, a->c[*p].ty + a->c[*p].bh / a->h
        };
        coords[c++] = (point) {
            x2 + w, -y2, a->c[*p].tx + a->c[*p].bw / a->w, a->c[*p].ty
        };
        coords[c++] = (point) {
            x2, -y2 - h, a->c[*p].tx, a->c[*p].ty + a->c[*p].bh / a->h
        };
        coords[c++] = (point) {
            x2 + w, -y2 - h, a->c[*p].tx + a->c[*p].bw / a->w, a->c[*p].ty + a->c[*p].bh / a->h
        };
    }

    /* Draw all the character on the screen in one go */
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof coords, coords, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, c);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(attribute_coord);
}

void display() {
    //float sx = 2.0 / glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    //float sy = 2.0 / glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    float sx = 2.0 / 800;
    float sy = 2.0 / 480;

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 480);

    glUseProgram(programBack);

    /* White background */
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    /* Enable blending, necessary for our alpha texture */
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glVertexAttribPointer(coordBack, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, fBackgroundPosition);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(coordBack);

    //glVertexAttribPointer(colorBack, 4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, VertexColors);
    //glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorBack);

    glVertexAttribPointer(texBack, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, VertexTexCoords);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texBack);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextures[0]);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    // Cleanup
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(coordBack);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(colorBack);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(texBack);

    glUseProgram(program);

    GLfloat black[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    GLfloat red[4] = { 1, 0, 0, 1 };
    GLfloat transparent_green[4] = { 0, 1, 0, 0.5 };

    /* Set color to black */
    //glUniform4fv(uniform_color, 1, black);

    /* Effects of alignment */
    render_text("The ñ Ñ Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", a48, -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 50 * sy, sx, sy);
    //render_text("The , . - + { } & % Misaligned Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", a48, -1 + 8.5 * sx, 1 - 100.5 * sy, sx, sy);

    ///* Scaling the texture versus changing the font size */
    //render_text("The ç ó Small Texture Scaled Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", a48, -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 175 * sy, sx * 0.5, sy * 0.5);
    //render_text("The Small Font Sized Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", a24, -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 200 * sy, sx, sy);
    //render_text("The Tiny Texture Scaled Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", a48, -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 235 * sy, sx * 0.25, sy * 0.25);
    //render_text("The Tiny Font Sized Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", a12, -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 250 * sy, sx, sy);

    ///* Colors and transparency */
    //render_text("The Solid Black Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", a48, -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 430 * sy, sx, sy);

    //glUniform4fv(uniform_color, 1, red);
    //render_text("The Solid Red Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", a48, -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 330 * sy, sx, sy);
    //render_text("The Solid Red Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", a48, -1 + 28 * sx, 1 - 450 * sy, sx, sy);

    //glUniform4fv(uniform_color, 1, transparent_green);
    //render_text("The Transparent Green Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", a48, -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 380 * sy, sx, sy);
    //render_text("The Transparent Green Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", a48, -1 + 18 * sx, 1 - 440 * sy, sx, sy);

    eglSwapBuffers(egldisplay, eglsurface);
}

void free_resources() {
    glDeleteProgram(program);
}

int init(void)
{
    Display    *x_display;
    Window      win;

    x_display = XOpenDisplay(":0");   // open the standard display (the primary screen)
    if (x_display == NULL) {
        std::cout << "cannot connect to X server" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(x_display);   // get the root window (usually the whole screen)

    XSetWindowAttributes  swa;
    swa.event_mask = ExposureMask | PointerMotionMask | KeyPressMask;

    win = XCreateWindow(   // create a window with the provided parameters
        x_display, root,
        0, 0, 800, 480, 0,
        CopyFromParent, InputOutput,
        CopyFromParent, CWEventMask,
        &swa);

    XMapWindow(x_display, win);             // make the window visible on the screen
    XStoreName(x_display, win, "GL test"); // give the window a name

    static const EGLint s_configAttribs[] =
    {
        EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE,    4,
        EGL_RED_SIZE,           5,
        EGL_GREEN_SIZE,         6,
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE,          5,
        EGL_ALPHA_SIZE,         0,
        EGL_SAMPLES,            0,
        EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS,     1,
        EGL_SAMPLES,            4,  // This is for 4x MSAA.
        EGL_NONE
    };


    EGLint numconfigs;

    egldisplay = eglGetDisplay((EGLNativeDisplayType)x_display);
    eglInitialize(egldisplay, NULL, NULL);
    assert(eglGetError() == EGL_SUCCESS);
    eglBindAPI(EGL_OPENGL_ES_API);

    eglChooseConfig(egldisplay, s_configAttribs, &eglconfig, 1, &numconfigs);
    assert(eglGetError() == EGL_SUCCESS);
    assert(numconfigs == 1);

    eglsurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(egldisplay, eglconfig, win, NULL);

    assert(eglGetError() == EGL_SUCCESS);
    EGLint ContextAttribList[] = { EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL_NONE };
    eglcontext = eglCreateContext(egldisplay, eglconfig, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, ContextAttribList);
    assert(eglGetError() == EGL_SUCCESS);
    eglMakeCurrent(egldisplay, eglsurface, eglsurface, eglcontext);
    assert(eglGetError() == EGL_SUCCESS);

    printf("VENDOR = %s\n", glGetString(GL_VENDOR));
    printf("RENDERER = %s\n", glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
    printf("VERSION = %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1)
        fontfilename = argv[1];
    else
        fontfilename = "FreeSans.ttf";

    init();

    init_resources();

    std::string sBackground = "back2.png";

    vLoadPngToTexture(sBackground, 0);

    //// this is needed for time measuring  -->  frames per second
    struct  timezone  tz;
    timeval  t1, t2;
    gettimeofday(&t1, &tz);
    int  num_frames = 0;

    while (1) {
        display();
        if (++num_frames % 30 == 0) {
        //if (++num_frames % 100 == 0) {
            gettimeofday(&t2, &tz);
            float dt = t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec + (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) * 1e-6;
            std::cout << "fps: " << num_frames / dt << std::endl;
            num_frames = 0;
            t1 = t2;
        }
        usleep(32000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I comment the line `render_text("The ñ Ñ Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", a48, -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 50 * sy, sx, sy);`, I can see the textured square perfectly.

Comment: I'm really surprised `text.v.glsl` compiled given that you're trying to jam int literals into floats in that `vec4` constructor on line 5 (no automatic type casts in GL's `#version 120` or in GLES' `#version 100`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`glUniform`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glUniform.xml) operates on the program object that was made part of current state by calling [`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glUseProgram.xml).

Because of that the call of `glUniform1i` in the function `atlas` is useless, because at this point there is no current program at all. You can delete this call, because you set the uniform later.

---

2. The texture `glTextures[iTexture]`, which you bind in the function `vLoadPngToTexture` is not generated.

Change your code somehow like this:

```
glGenTextures(1, glTextures+iTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextures[iTexture]);
```

---

3. You do not use an array buffer when you draw the background, but you use an array buffer when you draw the text. In the function `render_text` you bind `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);` but you never release it. This causes that the array buffer `vbo`is still bound when the background should be drawn in the next cycle. Becauseof that, [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml), in the function `display`, does not do what you expect it to do.

You can fix this by adding

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
```

to the end of the function  `render_text`.